# Android HttpUrlConnection not working properly

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I have been trying to send some information from an android application using the HttpUrlConnection to a PHP script online. I am very new to both PHP and have never used the HttpUrlConnection before so I am quite stuck as to why this is not working. There are no errors being thrown either.

my php script is

```
<?php

//get connection details from the app and then connect to db
$db_host = $_POST['db_host'];
$db_user = $_POST['db_user'];
$db_pass = $_POST['db_pass'];
$db_name = $_POST['db_name'];

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$device_group_id = $_POST['device_group_id'];

//create the new device group as a table in the database
$create_table_query = "CREATE TABLE" . $device_group_id . "(
        device_id varchar(24),
        device_alias varchar(24),
        device_longitute int,
        device_latititute int,
        device_group_id varchar(24)
)";

if (mysqli_query($con, $create_table_query)) {
    echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($con);
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

and the Asynctask method doInBackground() is

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    String result = "";
    try{
        //get values to pass to the PHP script
        Pair<String, String> dbHost = new Pair<>("db_host", DbConnectionInfo.DB_HOST);
        Pair<String, String> dbUser = new Pair<>("db_user", DbConnectionInfo.DB_USER);
        Pair<String, String> dbPass = new Pair<>("db_pass", DbConnectionInfo.DB_PASS);
        Pair<String, String> dbName = new Pair<>("db_host", DbConnectionInfo.DB_NAME);
        Pair<String, String> deviceGroupId = new Pair<>("device_group_id", "new_device_group");

        URL url = new URL("http://tracme.net16.net/create_device_group.php");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // prepare request
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

        //upload request
        OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8");
        writer.write(dbHost.first + "=" + dbHost.second);
        writer.write(dbUser.first + "=" + dbUser.second);
        writer.write(dbPass.first + "=" + dbPass.second);
        writer.write(dbName.first + "=" + dbName.second);
        writer.write(deviceGroupId.first + "=" + deviceGroupId.second);
        writer.close();
        outputStream.close();

        // read response
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { response.append(inputLine); }
        in.close();

        result = response.toString();

        // disconnect
        urlConnection.disconnect();

    }catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("Malformed URL Exception", "Malformed URL Exception");
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("IOException", "IOException");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: the php does not output anything if it doesn't fail.  so, have you checked the db to see if the table is created?  also, what are your plans for that table when that device returns - you can't REcreate the table, of course.

Comment: the strings in this example are just temporary values. each device will create a unique table in the database if not already created. this script is only actually run if the device does not have its own table already. the checks for this are performed in the java code.

Comment: I am at work so will have to check when i get home. I think the answer provided by m. Waqas perves is probably correct thinking about it!

Comment: yeah, i think he uncovered the issue - i'm upvoting since it's clear that there was no call to the query, and his additional messaging on the result of the query will help you debug, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code :

```
$device_group_id = $_POST['device_group_id'];

//create the new device group as a table in the database
$create_table_query = "CREATE TABLE" . $device_group_id . "(
    device_id varchar(24),
    device_alias varchar(24),
    device_longitute int,
    device_latititute int,
    device_group_id varchar(24)
)";
mysqli_close($con);
```

You are just creating a vairable name `$create_table_query` which just holds the query.There is no code that actually executes the query. Add this code before `mysqli_close($con);`

```
if ($con->query($create_table_query) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br>Table created<br>";
} else {
    echo "<br>Error creating table: " . $con->error. "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I have added this code, but still the table is not intact being created. not that I can see in phpMyAdmin anyway!

Comment: try running you php code from your Webroswer to see if it is working.

Comment: got it working thanks! I have accepted this answer as I think really this was the main issue, although i was also not leaving a space before the table name in my php script as well.